# JRebel Maven plugin + Eclipse + Weblogic

Tags: eclipse, maven, weblogic12c, jrebel

I am installing JRebel Maven plugin + Eclipse + Weblogic, adding this snippet  to my parent pom.xml.

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.zeroturnaround</groupId>
  <artifactId>jrebel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>generate-rebel-xml</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>generate</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

But when I run `mvn jrebel:generate`

I got this error:

```
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'jrebel' in the current project and in the plugin groups [com.oracle.weblogic, com.github.searls, com.cj.jshintmojo, com.github.phasebash, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (C:\Users\cabanilles\.m2\repository), 
intranetRepository (https://intranet/nexus/content/groups/public/), repository-apache-org (https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/public/), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoPluginFoundForPrefixException
```

Comment: Looks like a corrupted local repository, as from the stacktrace, Maven Central was tried and the prefix [is present there](https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/maven-metadata.xml). Can you remove the folder `~/.m2/repository/org/zeroturnaround` and run again?

Comment: same result :-(

Comment: Look at the POM and metadata that was downloaded, and see if it's the right thing.

Comment: Can you share the complete pom.xml in terms of `build`, `repositories` etc please. Just for info, all other repositories than the central does not have the plugin. https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/zeroturnaround/jrebel-maven-plugin/

Comment: Also can you confirm you are using Maven 3.0+ ?